# CakePHP - call_user_func_array() looses $this->request->data?

Tags: php, cakephp

I need to call Controller-methods dynamically. For this purpose I wrote the following code:

```
if(isset($method['postParams'])) {
    foreach($method['postParams'] as $index => $param) {
        $this->request->data[ $index ] = $param;
    }
}

App::import('Controller', $method['controller']);
// get result
$method['controller'] = $method['controller'] . 'Controller';
$Controller = new $method['controller']();

try {
    if(count($method['params'])) {
        $varVal = call_user_func_array(array($Controller, $method['method']), $method['params']);
    } else {
        $varVal = call_user_func(array($Controller, $method['method']));
    }
} catch(Exception $e) {
    $varVal = $e;
}
$this->set($varName, $varVal);
```

Now I debug the function being called and see that **$this->request->data** is **NULL**.

How to solve this?

Comment: Are you sure the controller has `$this->request->data` set on instantination? Simply does it always have it set when `__construct()` is called? If not - this is the reason.

Comment: Do you mean, if $this->request->data is set when call call_user_func_array() ? -> yes

Comment: No, i meant if after creating the `$Controller` variable ( $Controller = new $method['controller'](); ) - what does `var_dump($Controller->request)` print?

Comment: Faceplam. Thanks! $Controller->request->data instead of $this->request->data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the sake of completeness I'll post the answer to this problem for anyone having a similar issue to find the solution more easily.

**Instead of:**

```
$this->request->data
```

**Use:**

```
$Controller->request->data
```

*After* instanciating the `$Controller` object.